# background of content box

Tags: html, background, background-color, css

If an element has transparent but existing borders you can see that the background-color shows through the transparent borders: [Here's Proof](http://jsfiddle.net/inquisitive_web_developer/UbKBn/)

**How can I set a background-color that will only show in the content box?**

Comment: In a comment to a now deleted answer, you said: `"Sorry! This won't work in my situation. Transparent borders are required."`. Why do you *need* transparent borders?

Comment: @thirtydot it's complicated, and involves making triangles with CSS.

Comment: If you want to work within the confines of CSS2, then you probably have to rethink your approach. If you provide more detail about what you're trying to achieve (including more code), we might be able to offer a different approach that works for you. Is it not an option to just wrap your text in a <p> tag and assign the bg-color to it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/UbKBn/4/?

Comment: @squidbe Yes that is an option I was just thinking it could be done in CSS. Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `background-clip` with value `content-box`, but this is CSS3 ^^

`background-clip: content-box;`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure I want to use CSS3! I thought there was some attribute like background except for it's applied to the content box only.

Comment: I thought so ^^ I think you should use another way to perform your layout.

Comment: background-clip: content-box;